# Logged in, but cannot retrieve user from request object django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-login

I am trying to access my user object in the django request object in a Class Base View. However, i get the error: `module 'django.http.request' has no attribute 'user'`

Below is my code:

```
class FinanceHomePage(TemplateView):
template_name = 'finance/finance_homepage.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(FinanceHomePage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['username'] = self.request.user.username 
    return context
```

The above code snippet will be reached only after logging in.

** EDIT **
Below is the login view:

```
def user_login(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
       username = request.POST.get('username')
       password = request.POST.get('password')

       user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

       if user:
           if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('homepage'))  # main page if login is successful

           else:
                return HttpResponse("ACCOUNT NOT ACTIVE")

        else:
            print('Someone tried to log in and failed')
            print('Username: {}, password, {}'.format(username, password))
            return HttpResponse('Invalid login details supplied')

    else:
        return render(request, 'authentication/login.html', {})
```

Below is the directory of my self.request:

```
['COOKIES', 'FILES', 'GET', 'META', 'POST', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_cached_user', '_encoding', '_get_post', '_get_raw_host', '_get_scheme', '_initialize_handlers', '_load_post_and_files', '_mark_post_parse_error', '_messages', '_post_parse_error', '_read_started', '_set_post', '_stream', '_upload_handlers', 'body', 'build_absolute_uri', 'close', 'content_params', 'content_type', 'csrf_processing_done', 'encoding', 'environ', 'get_full_path', 'get_host', 'get_port', 'get_raw_uri', 'get_signed_cookie', 'is_ajax', 'is_secure', 'method', 'parse_file_upload', 'path', 'path_info', 'read', 'readline', 'readlines', 'resolver_match', 'scheme', 'session', 'upload_handlers', 'user', 'xreadlines']
```

Below is the fullstack trace of the error:

```
Traceback:

File "/anaconda3/envs/MyLife/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/anaconda3/envs/MyLife/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/anaconda3/envs/MyLife/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/anaconda3/envs/MyLife/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/anaconda3/envs/MyLife/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/anaconda3/envs/MyLife/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/anaconda3/envs/MyLife/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/anaconda3/envs/MyLife/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in get
  155.         context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)

File "/Users/kaijieang/Coding/MyLife/MyLife/finance/views/finance_index_view.py" in get_context_data
  10.         request.user.username

Exception Type: AttributeError at /finance/
Exception Value: module 'django.http.request' has no attribute 'user'
```

Comment: Can you update your question with your login views as well?

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM updated already

Comment: which version of django are you using?

Comment: @NiranjRajasekaran I am using python 3.6 with django 1.11

Comment: Maybe the user is not correctly authenticated, ask if user.is_authenticated() after user.authenticate(...) function

Comment: @NiranjRajasekaran sorry, i do not know how to make sure my print statement fits within the box. In anycase, is there a documentation for the login decorator? I have seen it though i am not sure how to use it.

Comment: Something weird is going on here; `self.request` should not be a module, but an instance of HttpRequest. And your print *does* show the user. Please show the *full* traceback and the full content of the view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Which view are you referring to? The two views are separate files and the Class Based View file is as simple as that. I have changed from `self.request` to `request`.

Comment: FinanceHomePage. `request` won't be defined at that point, so you'll get a NameError. Please show the full traceback from the original code though.

Comment: you have all correct middleware added in settings and in right order?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I dont know how to show the full traceback. The part which i shown is the full trace. And, shouldnt request be a global session like object easily accessed by any code?

Comment: @NoobEditor yupp

Comment: That's the bit I need. But you should switch back to `self.request`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman okay, i have done that, but i am not sure why my pyCharm has flagged the request in yellow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confused between `request`, which is a module imported at global level from `django.http`, and `self.request`, which is an attribute of the view instance. Although your code showed `self.request`, the error message shows that you were using `request` originally.

You should change it to `self.request`.

Comment: Thanks! I went to restart my pyCharm, and whatever bug that was plaguing the initial `self.request` is now gone. Although pyCharm is still flagging it yellow, it now works. Thanks a million!